# Fastest algorithm to find two strings that contains common characters

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to find whether two Java strings contain 2 common characters, which have to be next to each other.

I am using two for loops to check for that, but it seems slow, because I have to compute it again and again.

```
boolean contain2CommonChars(String s1, String s2) {
     for(){
       for() {
       }
    }
}
```

Is there an efficient algorithms to do that?

Secondly, what I really want to do is to find a sentence subset A from　a large sentence set B given another sentence x. If any sentence from B   has at least two common characters with sentence x, then put it into set A.

```
Set<String> findSubset(Set<String> B, String x){
    Set<String> A = new HashSet<>();

    ...
    return A;      
}
```

By the way, the size of B <10,000. Can the findSubset() be done within a very few millseconds?

EDIT: The 2nd questions is closed related to the 1st question. 
Example:

```
B = {"this is a dog", "this is a bat", "that was an dog "}
x = "this is not a cat"
```

I want to return:

```
A = {"this is a dog", "this is a cat"} //  because of "this is" or "is a"
```

Comment: What are the characters? For instance do you know they are letters? Are you looking for any pair of chars that appear in both strings?

Comment: They are unicode, specifically a mixture of Chinese and english characters

Answer (score 1):

> *Find whether two Java strings contain 2 common characters, which have to be next to each other.*

There can be a lot of edge cases but here is a way to do it (Might not be the fastest but can work depending on your needs).

- Iterate both the strings separately and create two `HashSets` for all 2-character pairs.

  For Example, `foobar` --> `fo`, `oo`, `ob`, `ba`, `ar`
- Just take an intersection of the above created `HashSets` to see if there are any common pairs.

It's quite hard to understand the second question. Maybe try including an example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

By iteration through every adjacent pair of the shortest of the 2 strings:

```
static boolean contain2CommonChars(String s1, String s2) {
    int l1 = s1.length();
    int l2 = s2.length();

    if ((l1 < 2) || (l2 < 2))
        return false;

    if (l2 < l1) {
        String temp = s1;
        s1 = s2;
        s2 = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - 1; i++){
        String pair = s1.substring(i, i + 2);
        if (s2.contains(pair))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "abcghj";
    String s2 = "shhcgop";

    System.out.println(s1 + " and " + s2 + " " + contain2CommonChars(s1, s2));

    String s3 = "abcghjlo";
    String s4 = "shhcop";

    System.out.println(s3 + " and " + s4 + " " + contain2CommonChars(s3, s4));
}
```

prints

```
abcghj and shhcgop true
abcghjlo and shhcop false
```

Answer (score 0):

Only answering the first question.

---

If you have the possibility of preprocessing the strings, for every string generate all pairs of characters and sort them increasingly.

```
contain2CommonChars -> 2C ai ar Ch co Co ha in mm mo n2 nC nt om on on rs ta
```

Now common pairs between two strings are found by a single merge-like pass taking at most O(L).